# Getting the subdomain URL for wordpress within Laravel project in PuTTy SSH

Tags: mysql, wordpress, .htaccess, putty

Not sure if this question was asked before but I've tried a few answers given within stack to resolve the setting up of a wordpress subdomain within a laravel project with no avail.

I have a folder structure set in puTTy as per

laravel project

> app
>
> config
>
> public
>
> > .htaccess
>
> resources
>
> .env
>
> ...
>
> wordpress
>
> > wp-config.php
> >
> > wp-content
> >
> > wp-includes
> >
> > .htaccess

the laravel project is running fine but I want to add wordpress as a subdomain e.g.
laravel.com/wordpress

on laravel .htaccess I've added a new line
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress[NC]`

and on wordpress's .htaccess with it's standard

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /laravel.com/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /laravel.com/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

i've also updated the database wp-option to set the url to http://laravel.com/wordpress on both the siteurl and home

however while expecting to be able to access the site locally via localhost/laravel/wordpress (it works)
but on the live server 
laravel.com/wordpress it returns a 404 page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have  fixed the issue by adding a new rewrite condition in the public level

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

which solved the issue of the page returning a 404 and showing my wordpress page just fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to add your WordPress code in your public directory of your laravel project